# Regularly varying distribution function

Tags: probability

Let
$$F(x)=2-2\Phi \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} \right)$$
with $x>0$ where $\Phi$ is the normal cummulative distribution function

a) Show that $G(x)=1-F(x)$ is regularly varying.

I'm having difficulties calculating the value for it and would appreciate some help.
To show regularly varying is to show that
$$\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{G(xt)}{G(t)}=x^\alpha$$

So I would then have $$\lim_{t->\infty}\frac{2\Phi(\sqrt\frac{1}{xt})-1}{2\Phi(\sqrt\frac{1}{t})-1}$$

my problem here is now once I write the cumulative distribution function as an integral, I don't know how to proceed.

I tried solving using L'Hospital's Rule as suggested and I got:
$$\lim_{t-> \infty}\frac{2*\frac{-1}{2}(xt)^{-3/2}\phi(\sqrt\frac{1}{xt})}{2*\frac{-1}{2}(t)^{-3/2}\phi(\sqrt\frac{1}{t})}$$
$$=x^{-3/2}$$
I got a different $\alpha$ from what the comment said was the solution. Could someone point me out where I made the mistake?

Comment: $(\alpha =-2)$. Follows easily by an application of L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Could you show me how ? I' not sure on how to do it.

Comment: @Alex: In estimating $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2\Phi\big(\sqrt\frac{1}{xt}\big)-1}{2\Phi\big(\sqrt\frac{1}{t}\big)-1}$$
as Kavi Rama Murty (and you tried) L'Hospital rule is applicable
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}2\Phi\big((xt)^{-1/2}\big) -1=0=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}2\Phi\big(t^{-1/2}\big)-1$$
$$\frac{2\Phi(\sqrt\frac{1}{xt})-1}{2\Phi(\sqrt\frac{1}{t})-1}\sim \frac{\phi\big((xt)^{-1/2}\big)x^{-1/2}t^{-3/2}}{\phi\big((t)^{-1/2}\big)t^{-3/2}}=x^{-1/2}\frac{\phi\big((xt)^{-1/2}\big)}{\phi\big((t)^{-1/2}\big)}\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow\infty}x^{-1/2}$$ you made a tiny mistake